# displaying listbox items according to textbox entry in C#

Tags: c#

I just want to ask that Is it possible to start displaying options(for the text entered in textbox) in the listbox as soon as the user starts typing in the textbox?

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: it is possible; if you want to continue asking, say, "How can I implement such a routine?" you'll have to provide more details (WinForms/WPF, your attempts etc.)

Comment: @DmirtyBychenko Thank You for the short answer.It is a windows form, and I have not tried any such thing in it as of now. Actually, I am not able to figure out how to proceed with it. Would be great if I get a reference link for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you're looking for something like this:

- Put `ListBox` on the form (`myListBox`)
- Put `TextBox` (`myTextBox` in the implementation below)
- Implement `TextChanged` event handler for the text box

Possible implementation

```
// When TextBox's Text changed
private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string textToFind = (sender as Control).Text;

  // Do all the changes in one go in order to prevent re-drawing (and blinking)
  myListBox.BeginUpdate();

  try {
    myListBox.SelectedIndices.Clear();

    // We don't want selecting anything on empty 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textToFind))
      return;

    for (int i = 0; i < myListBox.Items.Count; ++i) {
      string actual = myListBox.Items[i].ToString();

      // Now we should compare two strings; there're many ways to do this 
      // as an example let's select the item(s) which start(s) from the text entered, 
      // case insensitive
      if (actual.StartsWith(textToFind, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
        myListBox.SelectedIndices.Add(i);

        // can we select more than one item == shall we proceed?
        if (myListBox.SelectionMode == SelectionMode.One)
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  finally {
    myListBox.EndUpdate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Got an idea about how to proceed. :)